# Invalid Data Format Error - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to run a workbook that has VBA code attached to it. Whenever I attempt to run it though I am presented with an "Invalid Data Format" error. This is odd as all the other team members where I work are able to open and run the code on this file no problem. It is the exact same code as the workbook is being pulled from the same server. Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: What code? Are you all running the same version of Excel?

Comment: So it's code that verifies a bunch of FileDateTime() values. Everyone on the team is running Excel 2016. I would show the code but I can't even get into the sub to copy it.

Comment: Also the odd thing is I can run code on literally all of my other workbooks. Just the one is throwing an error.

Comment: If you can't get into the Sub to copy it, but we were magically able to tell you what was incorrect, how would you fix it??

Comment: That is the issue I am trying to fix. I am not able to access anything. Thanks for being super passive aggressive though.

Comment: who is the administrator of the file? id suggest that in the first instance

Comment: It is possible that the VBA Project has references to a COM Library that may not be present on your machine or is corrupted. To check what libraries it uses, on a system where it works, go to VBE (Alt+F11) and open Tools -> References. If you remove the offending reference, you may be able to open the file on your machine.